# Control Swiper with ScrollMagic

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js, scrollmagic

I've try to control a Swiper-Slider with ScrollMagic. Swiper is running in freemode, so I'm not able to use some of the native methods like `mySwiper.slideNext(speed, runCallbacks)`.

I've tried to move the slider by changing the transform-property of the swiper-wrapper element. Now the Slider is moving correctly but the active-class is not given to the visible slide inside the slider.

```
var sliderMove= new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: ".my-slider",
    triggerHook: 0,
    duration: '300%'
})
.setTween('.my-slider .swiper-wrapper', {'transform': 'translate3d(-2000px, 0px, 0px)'})
.addTo(controller)
```

The slider is moving quite well but as i said the classes fo the active slide is not given to the current slide. Is there a native to move the Swiper?

Answer (score 0):

Try somenthing like that:

```
<script>
swiper.on('slideChange', function() {
    jQuery(".my-slider .swiper-wrapper .item").removeClass("active");
    jQuery(".my-slider .swiper-wrapper .item-" + swiper.realIndex).addClass("active");
});
</script>
```

The best way to solve this is to use `slideChange` on slide changes.

The `swiper.realIndex` is the number of each slide to you apply the "active" to a specific one.

EDIT #1:

```
scene.on("change", function (event) {
    swiper.slideTo(index, 0);
});
```

Usage: `slideTo(index, speed, runCallbacks);`

Comment: It's not working. The function is not fired because I manipulate the transform of the swiper-wrapper by ScrollMagic. This means that the slider is not moving natively.

Comment: Then you should use `swiper.slideTo` to change the slides on scrollMagic scene changes. See an example above in **EDIT #1**.